# JSON append issues, want to get it inside the same square bracket

Tags: php, json

I have searched around for this, and couldnt find a good asnwer. Therefore I just created a question for myself. Please do link another question if it fits my question!.

My issue is that I am trying to append some data into a JSON file, but failing to do it correctly.

it looks like this:

```
[
   {"title":"test","start":"2017-07-03T10:00:00","end":"2017-07-03T16:00:00"}
]
```

When I append data into the file, it becomes like this:

```
[
   {"title":"test","start":"2017-07-03T10:00:00","end":"2017-07-03T16:00:00"}
]

{"title":"test","start":"2017-07-03T10:00:00","end":"2017-07-03T16:00:00"}
```

So the second one i appended in goes outside the square bracket. I want to get the appended data inside the same square bracket as the other one. If someone could help me out that would be much appreciated!

I tried to find a way to delete the closing square bracket, appending the data and then adding a new one, but that failed misarably.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: Are you attempting to append the JSON data in JavaScript or PHP? You tagged both.

Comment: tagged a little fast, sorry about that. I am appending with PHP

Comment: @Myhre - show **how** you are doing this

Comment: Json_decode the original, add the 2nd as an array and json_encode the resulting array.  In short, work with the data structures in php, and render the final result when it's correct as a php array.